# Jooq - UDT generation errors

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jooq

I recently changed the jooq generator on my project to be KotlinGenerator. One of the issues that I am currently facing is for UDT in certain views and tables.
I have tables that have fields of type Geometry in the database. When running jooq generator ( v3.14.1) there are compilation issues such as:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:<br/>protected/*protected and package*/

val CENTER_POINT: TableField<GeofenceRecord, Geometry?> = createField(DSL.name("center_point"), SQLDataType.GEOMETRY, this, "", JTSGeometryBinding())
```

Here is how my build.grade file looks:

```
generator {
    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator'
    database {
        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
        inputSchema = 'schemaname'
        forcedTypes {
            forcedType {
                userType = 'com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry'
                binding = 'net.dmitry.jooq.postgis.spatial.binding.JTSGeometryBinding'
                includeExpression = '.*'
                includeTypes = '(geometry.*|GEOMETRY.*|geography.*|GEOGRAPHY.*)'
            }
        }
    }
    generate {
        deprecated = false
        immutablePojos = false
        fluentSetters = true
        constructorPropertiesAnnotation = true
        pojos = true
        daos = true
        relations = true
        records = true
        interfaces = true
        pojosEqualsAndHashCode = true
        javaTimeTypes = true
    }
    target {
        packageName = 'projectname.jooq.schema'
        directory = 'build/generated-sources/jooq'
    }
    strategy.name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy"
}
```

Is there anything in the configurations that I am missing, for it to account for geometry data types ? It used to work when the name of the generator was 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'.

Comment: That kind of error can happen when the binding class first type parameter (the class to create geometries from) does not match the one inferred by Jooq (here, SQLDataType.GEOMETRY, I think). Can you attach your binding class to provide more information ?

Comment: @amanin: jOOQ version 3.14 didn't have `SQLDataType.GEOMETRY`, yet. It was added in jOOQ 3.16, only.

Comment: @LukasEder Ok, but why is it present in the first snippet in the question (2nd argument of the method) then ? Maybe the Jooq version used for generation differs from runtime version ? I do not see any version forced in the generator gradle configuration.

Comment: @amanin: Yeah, that's probably the answer to this question...